# Guava null tester keeps throwing error

Tags: java, junit, guava

Here is my piece of code:

```
public class MyTest {
    @NonNull 
    private MyObject MyObjectClient;

    private Object copyOfTestObject;

    public TestMyResult methodFoo(Object testobject) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        copyOfTestObject = clone(testObject);
    }


}
```

Now, i have a unit test for this class:

```
public class MyTestUnitTest {

    @Rule public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    private MyTest classUnderTest;

    @Test
    public void testNulls() {
        NullPointerTester nullPointerTester = new NullPointerTester();
        nullPointerTester.testConstructors(MyTest.class, NullPointerTester.Visibility.PACKAGE);
        nullPointerTester.testAllPublicInstanceMethods(classUnderTest);
    }
}
```

When I run the unit test, I keep getting this error: 
No exception thrown for parameter at index 1 from MyTest(MyObject, MyObject2) for class MyTest.

I am unclear why exactly this error is being thrown. Do I have to add the annotation @Nullable to te copyOfTestObject variable? If not, is there a way to have this unit test work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the issue is not with `methodFoo` but with the constructor `MyTest(MyObject, MyObject2)`... the `MyObject2` parameter is not `@Nullable`, your constructor isn't throwing an exception if `null` is passed in for it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Adding that annotation works. I wasn't completely sure if that's the root cause itself, but looks like it.